# Opencart 4 Remove /product From Url

Tags: php, url, opencart

Im Trying To move My site From Opencart 2 To Opencart 4 But I have Problem with Url, Here im trying to remove the /product from the url i managed to do it by changing the startup\seo url|rewrite from

```
return $url;
```

To

```
if(str_contains($url, '/product')) {
        $newPath = explode('product/', $url);
        return implode('',$newPath);
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
```

This Change helped with url But the problem is its not returnig the product page and redirect me to home page .

Comment: What exactly do you want your URL to look like?

Comment: The current url is  http://localhost/opencart-4.0.1.1/en/product/thierry-mugler-alien need to change it to http://localhost/opencart-4.0.1.1/en/thierry-mugler-alien

Answer (score 0):

You could add simple function before url generating:

```
<?php

$url = "localhost/opencart-4.0.1.1/en/product/thierry-mugler-alien";
$fixedURL = fixURL($url);
echo $fixedURL;

function fixURL ($url) {
  if (strpos($url, '/product') !== 0) {
      $newPath = explode('product/', $url);
      return implode('', $newPath);
  } else {
      return $url;
  }
}
?>
```

`$fixedURL` contains

> localhost/opencart-4.0.1.1/en/thierry-mugler-alien